# Add a gradle sourceset with folders for java, groovy, and resources

Tags: groovy, gradle, source-sets

I have a multi-module project where one of them adds a sourceSet in order to support 3 source folders

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
    componentTestCompile.extendsFrom compile, testCompile
    componentTestRuntime.extendsFrom runtime, testRuntime, componentTestCompile
}

sourceSets {
    componentTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/componentTest/java'
        }
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src/componentTest/groovy'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/componentTest/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.componentTestCompile
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath + configurations.componentTestRuntime
    }
}


task componentTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.componentTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.componentTest.runtimeClasspath
    reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/component")
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/component")

    println classpath
}

check.dependsOn componentTest
```

When executing gradle componentTest the Java code is not compiled (the build directory is not populated with the respective class files). 
However when applying the above sourceSet to a simple project (single module) it works. I'm a bit lost in figuring out what the problem is here. I have been playing with the expressions

```
compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.componentTestCompile
runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath + configurations.componentTestRuntime
```

But haven't really been able to get closer to a solution.

Comment: Which Java code is not getting compiled? `src/componentTest/java`?

Comment: I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MartinAhrer/8536263) to show the code that is producing the problem.

I have to refine my initial question. This is not really related to multi-module but to annotation processing.


The Groovy code references a Java class through an annotation 
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = [ComponentTestConfiguration.class])`.

This results in `unable to find class ComponentTestConfiguration.class` for annotation attribute constant` whereas a reference to another Java class (`new IshouldBeCompiled().configurationValue()`) is fine.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a build related problem. Does it work when you omit `.class`?

Comment: I agree, after adding a class reference within a method body which works I suspect that it is a Groovy compiler issue. Removing .class from the class literal just gives a different compiler error:
`Only classes and closures can be used for attribute classes in @org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration`.

Strangely it works when run from IDEA.

Comment: Upgraded to Gradle 1.10, works now!

Comment: Don't think it's really related to that, but good to hear it's now working. :-) The Groovy compiler error message likely means that the compiler didn't find the class on its compile class path.

Comment: Unfortunately when switching back to gradle 1.9 (on exactly the same code base) the error comes back. However I'm fine with 1.10!